Issue with in-place 2D fast fourier transform
I am implementing a 2D fft example using fftw library to understand how to work with it and I am having an issue for the in-place r2c case.
As far as I understood, I am doing it the way t was supposed to be done: i) having the memory allocated with the correct size (N_x * 2 * (N_y/2 + 1) that I've got from here) and ii) creating the plan passing the input as double* and passing it as output casting it to (fftw_complex*) type. However, the result is not matching the out-of-place r2c neither the in-place c2c that I've implemented.
The code to run those three cases and compare is given below:
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // define parameters
    int N_x = 20;
    int N_y = 20;
    int N_y_complex = N_y/2 + 1;

    double a = 2;
    double b = 2;

    double range_x = 10;
    double range_y = 10;

    double dx = range_x/(N_x);
    double dy = range_y/(N_y);

    ////////////////////////////////////////// OUT-OF-PLACE R2C TRANSFORM //////////////////////////////////////////

    // declare functions
    double *in = (double*)fftw_malloc(N_x * N_y * sizeof(double));
    fftw_complex *out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(N_x * N_y_complex * sizeof(fftw_complex));

    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        double x = i*dx;
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            double y = j*dy;
            
            if(fabs(x) <= a/2 && fabs(y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else if(fabs(range_x - x) <= a/2 && fabs(range_y - y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else if(fabs(x) <= a/2 && fabs(range_y - y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else if(fabs(range_x - x) <= a/2 && fabs(y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                in[i*N_y + j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if the function is even
    bool is_even = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_x / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N_y; j++) {
            int i_neg = (N_x - i) % N_x;
            int j_neg = (N_y - j) % N_y;

            if (in[i * N_y + j] != in[i_neg * N_y + j_neg]) {
                cout << "Symmetry error: f(" << i * dx << "," << j * dy << ") = " << in[i * N_y + j] 
                     << " but f(" << i_neg * dx << "," << j_neg * dy << ") = " << in[i_neg * N_y + j_neg] << endl;
                is_even = false;
                cout << i << ", " << j << " || " << i_neg << ", " << j_neg  <<  endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Checking f(x,y) parity: " << endl;
    if (is_even) {
        cout << "   The function is even." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "   The function is not even." << endl;
    }

    fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N_x,N_y,in,out,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);

    ////////////////////////////////////////// IN-PLACE C2C FORWARD TRANSFORM //////////////////////////////////////////

    fftw_complex *in2 = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(N_x * N_y * sizeof(fftw_complex));

    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            in2[i*N_y + j][0] = in[i*N_y + j];
            in2[i*N_y + j][1] = 0;
        }
    }

    fftw_plan p_inPlace_c2c = fftw_plan_dft_2d(N_x, N_y, in2, in2, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p_inPlace_c2c);

    bool success = false;
    double tol = 1e-10;

    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y/2; j++){

            if(abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][0] - in2[i * N_y_complex + j][0]) > tol && abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][1] - in2[i * N_y_complex + j][1]) > tol){
                success = false;
                goto skiploop;
            }
            else{
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }

skiploop:

    cout << "Checking if in-place (forward C2C) and out-of-place results are matching: " << endl;
    if(success == true){
        cout << "   Matching results for in-place c2c and out-of-place" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "   Something went wrong" << endl;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////// IN-PLACE R2C TRANSFORM //////////////////////////////////////////

    // Calculate padded size: N_x * 2 * (N_y/2 + 1) = N_x * 2 * N_y_complex
    int padded_size = N_x * 2 * N_y_complex;

    // Allocate enough memory to hold complex data
    double *in3 = (double*)fftw_malloc(padded_size * sizeof(double));

    // Assign values for the real function to be transformed
    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            in3[i*N_y + j] = in[i*N_y + j];
        }
    }

    // Create plan casting in3 to fftw_complex type
    fftw_plan p_inPlace_r2c = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N_x, N_y, in3, (fftw_complex*)in3, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    // Execute plan
    fftw_execute(p_inPlace_r2c);

    // printing first real value for debugging:
    cout << "out-of-place r2c: " << out[0][0] << " || in-place c2c: " << in2[0][0] << " || in-place r2c: " << ((fftw_complex*)in3)[0][0] << endl;

    // Check final results compared to out-of-place transform
    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y/2; j++){

            if(abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][0] - ((fftw_complex*)in3)[i * N_y_complex + j][0]) > tol && abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][1] - ((fftw_complex*)in3)[i * N_y_complex + j][1]) > tol){
                success = false;
                goto skiploop2;
            }
            else{
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }

skiploop2:

    cout << "Checking if in-place (R2C) and out-of-place results are matching: " << endl;
    if(success == true){
        cout << "   Matching results for in-place r2c and out-of-place" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "   Something went wrong" << endl;
    }

    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    fftw_free(in2);
    fftw_free(in3);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p_inPlace_c2c);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p_inPlace_r2c);

}

The print statement I've put to get the first real value for all three cases displays:
out-of-place r2c: 25 || in-place c2c: 25 || in-place r2c: -2.58976e+284

What am I missing in this case? I am compiling it as g++ -I/path/to/include -o fft2d fft2d.cpp -L/path/to/lib -lfftw3, because the machine I am working on has the fftw library in a custom directory.

Check the documentation.  Each ROW of the incoming data has to be padded out with the extra columns.  You're just cramming all the extra space at the end.  https://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html

Great! I thought that the extra padding should be added just at the end, because I had understood that the extra padding would only matter while overriding the new complex values. But it is working fine now! Thank you very much!
I will add the answer here with the updated code and giving you credit :)

Thanks to @TimRoberts for clarifying this for me! I had thought that the extra padding would only matter while overriding the array with the new complex values, so I've just left all the extra space at the end of in3.
So, working with representing the 2D array as a 1D row-major array, I needed to modify this part of the code to ensure all the extra padding would be placed in the correct position corresponding to the end of each row:
    // Assign values for the real function to be transformed
    int extra_row_padding;
    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            if(N_y % 2 == 0){
                extra_row_padding = 2;
            }
            else{
                extra_row_padding = 1;
            }
            in3[i*(N_y + extra_row_padding) + j] = in[i * N_y + j];
        }
    }

Here it is the full working example:
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // define parameters
    int N_x = 20;
    int N_y = 20;
    int N_y_complex = N_y/2 + 1;

    double a = 2;
    double b = 2;

    double range_x = 10;
    double range_y = 10;

    double dx = range_x/(N_x);
    double dy = range_y/(N_y);

    ////////////////////////////////////////// OUT-OF-PLACE R2C TRANSFORM //////////////////////////////////////////

    // declare functions
    double *in = (double*)fftw_malloc(N_x * N_y * sizeof(double));
    fftw_complex *out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(N_x * N_y_complex * sizeof(fftw_complex));

    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        double x = i*dx;
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            double y = j*dy;
            
            if(fabs(x) <= a/2 && fabs(y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else if(fabs(range_x - x) <= a/2 && fabs(range_y - y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else if(fabs(x) <= a/2 && fabs(range_y - y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else if(fabs(range_x - x) <= a/2 && fabs(y) <= b/2){
                in[i*N_y + j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                in[i*N_y + j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Check if the function is even
    bool is_even = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_x / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N_y; j++) {
            int i_neg = (N_x - i) % N_x;
            int j_neg = (N_y - j) % N_y;

            if (in[i * N_y + j] != in[i_neg * N_y + j_neg]) {
                cout << "Symmetry error: f(" << i * dx << "," << j * dy << ") = " << in[i * N_y + j] 
                     << " but f(" << i_neg * dx << "," << j_neg * dy << ") = " << in[i_neg * N_y + j_neg] << endl;
                is_even = false;
                cout << i << ", " << j << " || " << i_neg << ", " << j_neg  <<  endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Checking f(x,y) parity: " << endl;
    if (is_even) {
        cout << "   The function is even." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "   The function is not even." << endl;
    }

    fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N_x,N_y,in,out,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);

    ////////////////////////////////////////// IN-PLACE C2C FORWARD TRANSFORM //////////////////////////////////////////

    fftw_complex *in2 = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(N_x * N_y * sizeof(fftw_complex));

    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            in2[i*N_y + j][0] = in[i*N_y + j];
            in2[i*N_y + j][1] = 0;
        }
    }

    fftw_plan p_inPlace_c2c = fftw_plan_dft_2d(N_x, N_y, in2, in2, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p_inPlace_c2c);

    bool success = false;
    double tol = 1e-10;

    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y/2; j++){

            if(abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][0] - in2[i * N_y_complex + j][0]) > tol && abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][1] - in2[i * N_y_complex + j][1]) > tol){
                success = false;
                goto skiploop;
            }
            else{
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }

skiploop:

    cout << "Checking if in-place (forward C2C) and out-of-place results are matching: " << endl;
    if(success == true){
        cout << "   Matching results for in-place c2c and out-of-place" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "   Something went wrong" << endl;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////// IN-PLACE R2C TRANSFORM //////////////////////////////////////////

    // Calculate padded size: N_x * 2 * (N_y/2 + 1) = N_x * 2 * N_y_complex
    int padded_size = N_x * 2 * N_y_complex;

    // Allocate enough memory to hold complex data
    double *in3 = (double*)fftw_malloc(padded_size * sizeof(double));

    // Assign values for the real function to be transformed
    int extra_row_padding;
    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y; j++){
            if(N_y % 2 == 0){
                extra_row_padding = 2;
            }
            else{
                extra_row_padding = 1;
            }
            in3[i*(N_y + extra_row_padding) + j] = in[i * N_y + j];
        }
    }

    // Create plan casting in3 to fftw_complex type
    fftw_plan p_inPlace_r2c = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N_x, N_y, in3, (fftw_complex*)in3, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    // Execute plan
    fftw_execute(p_inPlace_r2c);

    // printing first real value for debugging:
    cout << "out-of-place r2c: " << out[0][0] << " || in-place c2c: " << in2[0][0] << " || in-place r2c: " << ((fftw_complex*)in3)[0][0] << endl;

    // Check final results compared to out-of-place transform
    for(int i = 0; i < N_x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N_y/2; j++){

            if(abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][0] - ((fftw_complex*)in3)[i * N_y_complex + j][0]) > tol && abs(out[i * N_y_complex + j][1] - ((fftw_complex*)in3)[i * N_y_complex + j][1]) > tol){
                success = false;
                goto skiploop2;
            }
            else{
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }

skiploop2:

    cout << "Checking if in-place (R2C) and out-of-place results are matching: " << endl;
    if(success == true){
        cout << "   Matching results for in-place r2c and out-of-place" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "   Something went wrong" << endl;
    }

    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    fftw_free(in2);
    fftw_free(in3);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p_inPlace_c2c);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p_inPlace_r2c);

}

